# How to reverse rows of Daru::DataFrame?

Tags: daru

Given a `Daru::DataFrame` object, how do I reverse the order of rows?

For example...

```
> Daru::DataFrame.new([{a: 2, b: 2}, {a: 1, b: 3}, {a: 3, b:1}])
=> #<Daru::DataFrame(3x2)>
       a   b
   0   2   2
   1   1   3
   2   3   1
```

When I have data frame like above, how can I just reverse the order of rows, to obtain the DataFrame of

```
a   b
3   1
1   3
2   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```rb
df.sort [:a], ascending: false
```

Comment: This command will sort the rows by column `:a`'s value, not reversing the given rows...

Comment: `df.reindex Daru::Index.new([0,1,2].reverse)`

Comment: Thanks, the answer given in above comment solved the problem.  Can you include the code in comment to the answer so that I can accept it as an answer?